# How to check a service account is built-in network service account?

Tags: windows-services

I need to check if service account in the form of (xxx\yyy$) is an built-in network service account. 
One way I'm thinking is compare account name with "domainName\hostname$", it's networkservice account if equals; otherwise not.

I believe there's some simple API (C/C++) can help me. Anybody know it?

Comment: Are you talking about a remote server name?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare the actual SID. The sids of these well-known users are declared.

See [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330) at Microsoft, where you will find:

> SID: S-1-5-20
>
> Name: NT Authority
>
> Description: Network Service